# How do I put the app.php and app_dev.php inside a sub folder

Tags: symfony, mod-rewrite

Since we have multiple apps on the same site (and all apps related to a big project), I place multiple apps inside the web folder like this:

web /

|-- frontend

|-- backend

|-- api

Each should have its own app.php and app_dev.php. It is possible to place the frontend's app.php and app_dev.php right under root but that kinda breaks the nice structure we are trying to keep.

I'm trying to use these rules in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^app_dev\.php.*$ frontend/app_dev.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/app_dev.php [QSA,L]
```

Seems to work fine, except the fact that all links generated now have the prefix 'frontend' like this: abc.com/frontend/usual-route

Is there anyway to tell Symfony to ignore the frontend part in this case?

Comment: Why don't you simply use routes pointing to different controllers depending on your application? I mean, that's what they're here for.

Answer (score 2):

you need to override the router's request context base url.

Add this to your `app/config/paramters.yml`:

```
parameters:
   router.request_context.base_url: /
```

See the documentation chapter [Configuring the Request Context Globally](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html#configuring-the-request-context-globally).

Please note that you need a symfony version >= 2.2.0 to use this feature.

Comment: thank you very much, that works. Amazingly easy once you know how. BTW, I wonder if you have experience with htaccess rule? In my question above, if I comment out the line "RewriteRule ^app_dev\.php.*$ frontend/app_dev.php [QSA,L]" then everything works just fine but otherwise the stylesheets inside frontend/ will not be loaded correctly. I'm putting that line there hoping to be able to access the app_dev.php via the link mysite.com/app_dev.php

Comment: I would recommend you not to use the app_dev.php page on a publicly accessible domain as you will easily expose sensible information like container parameters. Better use environment variables to switch between environments in your `app.php`. As you're using Apache there is `SetEnvIf` ... So you could let Apache set the environment variable (i.e. `SYMFONY__DEV_MODE=true` ) if a certain key/value pair in the request header is found. in your dev environment you can use `SetEnv` to have symfony always show in dev environment under a certain local domain.

Comment: Thank you for your advice nifr. Actually app dev will be used only on the local env, and since everyone is already used to having that app_dev.php prefix in our local env I was just wondering if I could do the same while leaving the real file in the sub folder.

Comment: Seem like 'RewriteRule ^app_dev\.php$ /frontend/app_dev.php [QSA,L]' works, but for some reason the routes generated on the site then all have the prefix /frontend/, even though router.request_context.base_url is set to '/'. Very weird. The normal, no app_dev.php links work fine tho.